# no vim color when using SSH from mac to linux

Tags: linux, macos, vim, ssh

I installed [gruvbox colorscheme](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox) both on my mac and my linux machine.
The colorscheme is working on both machines individually.
But when connect to my linux machine via SSH, no colors are displayed on my mac screen.

On my mac and on my server, locally:
[image: mac screen wo ssh]

On my mac, using SSH (connected to my linux machine on which I have the same vim configuration):
[image: mac screen using ssh]

What I tried:

- in my .vimrc : `set termguicolors`
- `:syntax on`
- `:syntax enable`
- When I `$echo $TERM` I get `xterm-256color` (on both machines)

Comment: You dont want set termguicolors for ssh connections, I believe, simply because i doubt ssh supports the 24-bit color stuff. Also, mac’s Terminal app doesn’t, so which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: Please self-answer if you were able to solve your problem!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. There is a Vim Stack Exchange. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: my image illustrate only the colorscheme, we don't care about the code in the picture.

Comment: @Rob while I agree in spirit, the image here is related to graphics, not text.

Comment: Apologies for the complaint. I see that error so often that sometimes my trigger finger is faster than my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: I just removed `set termguicolors` from the .vimrc and it worked.